# jQuery animated navbar not working in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hi – i have a navbar at the bottom. This element slidesDown when the #controls-wrapper has a mouseenter. Additionally there is a callback to adjust another pageelement, so i won't get covered by the navbar. I tested the script on browserstack and it works for firefoxes, safaris and chromes, but not for internet explorers. In IE nothing happens.
Is there something specific to be considered for IE and my code wrong? Thanks for your interest. regards theo

```
/*animated Navbar at the bottom*/
$(function() {
var speed = 400;
var $window = $(window);
$('#controls').hide();

if ($window.width() > 640) {

$('#controls-wrapper').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#controls').stop().slideDown(speed,'easeInQuad', function(){
    $(".page-id-16 .textcol, .page-id-42
    .textcol").stop().animate({marginBottom: "31px"}, speed );
    });
    });

$('#controls').mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).stop().delay(2000).slideUp(speed,'easeInQuad', function(){
    $(".page-id-16 .textcol, .page-id-42
    .textcol").stop().animate({marginBottom: "-31px"}, speed);
    });
    });
    }
else{

    $('#controls').hide();
    $('#controls-wrapper').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#controls').stop().slideUp(speed,'easeInQuad');
    });
    }
});
```

And the css for #control-wrapper and #controls

```
#controls-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 2
}
#controls {
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
z-index: 2
}
```

Comment: Rule number 6: What version of IE are we debugging for?

Comment: words `IE` and `6` in same sentence, bad memories!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't speak Italian.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8,9,10 – Yes and i do speak italian and i know where pantheon is. Thanks

Comment: Is that how the jquery code is actually formatted on your page? I wouldn't be surprised if the line breaks after `.page-id-42 ..` are causing IE fits. Also, are you declaring a doctype?

Comment: yes i declare a doctype `(function($) {...})(jQuery);` i don't see two points after .page-id-42

Comment: ok, i suppose something is wrong with the way i write the callback. Can you give me hint?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code, that works well. The cause is the element that should trigger the animation. Internet explorer does not recognize this element if it has no background-color or another content. Background-color: transparent does not help either. So, i'll have to take another approach. But anyway thanks for the help in this forum, see you all in pantheon. theo

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.
Internet Explorer (8,9,10 and probably even higher, not confirmed) does not recognize an element that only defines an area but lacks background-color or another content. When i assign a background-color to element #controls-wrapper, then i works well.

Possible workaround:
Fill the area #controls-wrapper with an invisible Element

```
#controls-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(rgba.php?name=black&a=00) repeat;//invisible
 }
```

The php that provides the element:
https://github.com/LeaVerou/rgba.php/blob/master/rgba.php

With this workaround the jquery code displayed in the question works.
There may be a better solution, though.
good luck